# Jhipster Registry Release 3.2.4 - can't change admin password

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm using [registry release 3.2.4](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/releases/tag/v3.2.4) on Windows environnement (dev).

I want to change the default admin password.

According the [documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#security) I just need to define `security.user.password` on my `application-*.yml` file.

So my `central-config/application-dev.yml` become

```
jhipster:
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production
    registry:
        password: admin123
```

I start my registry `java -jar jhipster-registry/jhipster-registry-3.2.4.war --spring.profiles.active=swagger,dev,native` (the parameter `--spring.profiles.active`is set here just to be sure my config file is correctly load).

I try to connect on http://127.0.0.1:8761/#/ with admin user...but my new password doesn't work (just the default "admin" password still work).

When the registry launch, i've got these warnings

```
WARN 1152 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
WARN 1152 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with key 'zuulEndpoint' has been registered as an MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations
```

And when i try to connect, this warning

```
WARN 1152 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : No routes found from RouteLocator
```

When i look the config load on my application, it's look all right
[My cloud configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCntt.png)

I try to add `-e JHIPSTER_SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION_JWT_SECRET=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production` and `-e SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin123` when i launch my registry, but still don't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Password has to be set in 2 places; in the application.yml of the registry and in the registry clients (the services and gateways) in their own `bootstrap.yml` because properties in central-config are read only once the app has been able to connect to the registry.

You can also set it in an environment variable `SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD` and use placeholders in those files to avoid exposing it in your git repo while managing it in a single place.

Comment: Thanks for this response but i still have my issue. 
I've got on my `central-config\application.yml` and `central-config\boostrap.yml` this configuration. 
`jhipster:
    registry:
        password: admin123`
But i can sill connect on http://127.0.0.1:8761 with admin/admin.
When I look on http://127.0.0.1:8761/#/config I've got `jhipster.registry.password: admin123`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to cope with the same issue with JHipster Registry 4.1.1. As the documentation and the command line option stated to use spring.security.user.password property I've updated my application.yml as follow

```
jhipster:
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production
spring:
    security:
        user:
            password: admin1234
```

It works as expected for me.